# Securing a PHP web application that runs locally (https)

Tags: https, local, wampserver

I have a PHP / Mysql web application for business management that runs on a local server (Wampserver 2.5)

each customer has a local server on which Wampserver and the application are installed (they cannot connect to a remote server due to the instability of the internet ...)

Because of the latest update of browsers, HTTP pages are opened with a "red unsecured": it is really badly seen by the customers?

I installed SSL on Wampserver but the self-signed certificate is also not valid on the browser

[image]

Could you suggest me a solution for that

Comment: Your user has to accept the self signed certificate, then it will show nicely on their browser

Comment: You cannot : https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/